# Using Excel Macros to Search on Website If Word Exist or not

Tags: excel

I am having an excel sheet with A1-A200 URL's. Since I am newbie in macros, I would like to ask if there is a macros which opens the website with in excel (Not opening in browser) and search for the sentence for example: "there is an error" if the word exist return with "Yes" in B1 otherwise No.

Thanks in advance. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you should have a look here to get the content of a web page:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738427/vba-script-to-navigate-webpage-and-download-csvs. The code is to download a file but I guess the ```http.responseBody``` will let you have the html content. Then you can search it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the InternetExplorer of VBA and goto the webpages and lok at the html.
This code loops from 1 to 200 and uses the url in column A and searches with instr if "there is an error" exists.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer


Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

For i = 1 To 200
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate Range("A" & i).Value

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ie.document
    If InStr(html.DocumentElement.innerHTML, "there is an error") Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes"
    Else
        Range("B" & i).Value = "No"
    End If
Next i

Set ie = Nothing
```

You need to add two references. Go to tools -> References and add "Microsoft Internet Controls" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library"

Comment: I am sorry this did not work for me

Compile Error Invalid Outside procedure

Comment: Oh.. sorry forgot one step. You need to add a reference. Go to tools -> References and add "Microsoft Internet Controls".

Comment: and what should be the sub or function?

Comment: I believe either can work but I suppose a sub is easier to work with.

Comment: You need to wrap the code in a sub https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwfyw.png , and I now noticed you need Microsoft HTML Object Library too in the references.

Comment: code is working smoothly but i guess there is a possible error with urls